# Fixed window size with FlaskWeb

Tags: python-3.x, flask, frontend

Im creating a Desktop app with python with a Web based front-end and for it im using Flask because I readed is more beginer friendly than other frameworks. As i wanted it to be a desktop app Im using aswell the FlaskWebGUI library so when runing the code it opens a window and not the browser, but I want the window to have a fixed size and I dont know if its possible.
The app right now only has a image that when clicked it changes the theme from dark to light mode and viceversa.

This is the python code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from random import randint
from flaskwebgui import FlaskUI

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #app.run()
    FlaskUI(app=app, width=600, height=600, server='flask').run()
```

This is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/main.css">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="static/favicon.png">
        <title>APP Try</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="static/img/sun.png" id="switch">
        <script>
            var icon = document.getElementById("switch");

            icon.onclick = function(){
                document.body.classList.toggle("light-mode");
                if (document.body.classList.contains("light-mode")) {
                    icon.src = "static/img/moon.png";
                } else {
                    icon.src = "static/img/sun.png";
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the CSS code:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik:700|Rubik:400');

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 {
  font-family: 'Rubik';
  font-weight: 700;
}

html {font-size: 100%;} /* 16px */

h1 {font-size: 5.652rem; /* 90.4px */}

h2 {font-size: 3.997rem; /* 64px */}

h3 {font-size: 2.827rem; /* 45.28px */}

h4 {font-size: 1.999rem; /* 32px */}

h5 {font-size: 1.414rem; /* 22.56px */}

small {font-size: 0.707rem; /* 11.36px */}

:root {
  --text: #E1E1E1;
  --background: #37373C;
  --primary: #2D2D32;
  --secondary: #28282D;
  --accent: #0F7DE1;
}

.light-mode {
  --text: #1E1E1E;
  --background: #C3C3C8;
  --primary: #CDCDD2;
  --secondary: #D2D2D7;
  --accent: #1E8CF0;
}

body{
  background-color: var(--background);
  color: var(--text);
  font-family: 'Rubik';
  font-weight: 400;
}
```